# Orientation issue when capture image with camera2 api

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-camera2

I use the camera2 API to capture a photo and set my screen orientation as portrait. I found that there are different behaviors when it captures photos in landscape mode from two devices.

Device 1 can display photo properly, but device 2 display upside down photo. **Here is my code:**

```
static {
   ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
   ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
   ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
   ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
} 

private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
    return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
}
....
mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
int rotation = currentOrientation
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));
....
```

I use OrientationEventListener to detect rotation

```
@Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        int currentOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
        if (orientation >= 330 || orientation < 30) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
        } else if (orientation >= 60 && orientation < 120) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
        } else if (orientation >= 150 && orientation < 210) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
        } else if (orientation >= 240 && orientation < 300) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
        }
        if (prevOrientation != currentOrientation && orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
            prevOrientation = currentOrientation;
            if (currentOrientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                Log.i(TAG, "currentOrientation : " + currentOrientation);
                uxOrientationChanged(currentOrientation);
            }

        }
    }
```

I also compare the value for two device and have same value of rotation and mSensorOrientation, can anyone help? Thanks